# In Bluez A2DP: how can I modify the default audio sample rate

Tags: bluez, a2dp

I am using Bluez4 to sink Audio from an iphone 5 to a Raspberry pi audio output. 
The default settings for BLuez 4 A2DP appear to be S16_LE, 44,1kHz Stereo.

Similar to other posts about Bluez, I can't catch Select_Configuration DBus messages in order to change the sample rate dynamically. Instead I decided to try to find the default A2DP sample rate in the BLuez Stack.

Does anyone know where the default sample rate is set? My first thought was that it was in the BLuez/audio/ folder but nothing appears to change the default 44.1kHz sample rate.
Now I'm very curious to know where it is set.

Currently using this: `sudo ./a2dp-alsa --sink | aplay -c 2 -r 44100 -f S16`
would like to use this `sudo ./a2dp-alsa --sink | aplay -c 2 -r 16000 -f S16`

Answer (score 0):

I came across these lines in `a2dp-alsa.c`

```c
/* Initialise connection to ALSA */
g_handle = audio_init("hw:0,0", 48000);
```

maybe its hard coded in `a2dp-alsa` - not parameterizable